# Mac mini Apple bluetooth keyboard DELETE key can't do 'backward delete'

Tags: mac, keyboard, mac-mini

I have mac mini and I bought an original apple bluetooth keyboard from ebay. The problem is that the DELETE key always do 'DELETE' action and not 'Backspace', even if I use the function key with it. The same problem is occurred on both windows and osx 10.8 in my mac mini. Please help me guys. Thanks!

Comment: Do other key combinations that use fn (like fn-down for page down) work?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it does for me: "fn" "delete" does a backward delete.